# Remote plink ssh program ends prematurely

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, plink

I have a program that can be run via remote plink ssh on a different PC using windows command prompt

```
plink [username]@[ip address] -pw [password] ./program
```

or:

```
plink -ssh -l [username] -pw [password] [ip address] ./program
```

but somehow the program will end prematurely. Program runs, but terminates before the program had run its course. It doesn't happen to all my programs though.

To clearify, I can run my program with following command line

```
plink [username]@[ip address] -pw [password]
```

which log me in to remote system, from there I can run `./program` to its entirety.

but if I try `plink [username]@[ip address] -pw [password] ./program` in one line, it will quit in the middle.

I wonder if anyone encounter the same problem before? How do you solve it? Thanks

Comment: "just the programs that access RAM"? I'm tempted to ask for examples of programs that *don't* access RAM, but I'm afraid someone would actually come up with a valid specimen...

Comment: Sorry, it is a stupid thing to say. I meant to be DMA.

Comment: What does `./program` do? How does it interact with the terminal?

Comment: it is a command that can run on terminal, but there is no further interaction beyond that (i.e no additional user input besides `./Program`)

Answer (score 0):

plink [username]@[ip address] -pw [password] -m program.txt

Execute remote commands from local file. You can create a local command file with Unix commands in it, and run it remotely and automatically. Example -- "find /usr/local -name pmapp -print" in cmds.txt can be run with:

so use -m option that help you to execute remote commands

cheers.